# Bootstrap navigation not working even after keeping js on top

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

Bootstrap toggler not working. The icon is visible but after reducing browser size its not dropping links. I read other solutions also but mostly says load javascript before bootstrap, I tried loading js at first before bootstrap also but still it's not working. Below is the code I am using

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name = "viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">


    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="Bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="Bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel ="stylesheet">
    <script  src ="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;">

<title>HTML Test</title>
</head>
<body >
                        <!-- Container -->
    <div class=”container”>                         
                        <!-- Navigation  -->
        <nav class="navbar sticky-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">        
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navigation Bar</a>
            <button class ="navbar-toggler" type ="button" data-toggler="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportContent" aria-expanded="flase" aria-lable ="Toggle navigation">
                <span class = "navbar-toggler-icon" ></span>
            </button>
                            <!-- links -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportContent">
                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">About Us</a>
                    </li>
                            <!-- Drop down  -->
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href ="#" data-toggle ="dropdown">More</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 1</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 2</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 3</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 4</a>
                            </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Logout</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
                    <!-- Search Button and text column -->
            <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" >
                <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-lable="Search">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-sucess my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
            </form>
        </nav>

                    <!-- pagination  -->
        <nav aria-lable="pageNavigation" >
            <ul class="pagination justify-content-end">
                <li class="pagination-item"><a Class="page-link" href="#">Previous</a></li>
                <li class="pagination-item"><a Class="page-link" href="#">1</a></li>
                <li class="pagination-item"><a Class="page-link" href="#">2</a></li>
                <li class="pagination-item"><a Class="page-link" href="#">3</a></li>
                <li class="pagination-item"><a Class="page-link" href="#">Next</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a typo in the toggler button. It should be `data-toggle="collapse"` not `data-toggler="collapse"`.

```
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportContent" aria-expanded="flase" aria-lable="Toggle navigation">
       <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
```